# Can't get UpdatePanel to refresh on GridView paging

Tags: asp.net, ajax, gridview, paging

I have a GridView in an UpdatePanel (ASP.Net 2.0) .

I have this code for the PageIndexChanging method of the grid view:

```
   protected void grdProductSearch_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
   {
            grdProductSearch.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            grdProductSearch.DataBind();
   }
```

For the UpdatePanel, in the Triggers collection I have added the GridView and the PageIndexChanging method for the EventName.

Yet, the grid displays data correctly but there is no response when I click the page numbers at the bottom. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Since your gridview in the updatepanel, No need to add trigger for paging.

Comment: have you set gridview datasource as objectdatasource?

Comment: In PageIndexchanging event, where you bind data to grid, make sure, data is again fetched from the DB

Comment: .... In PageIndexchanging event, where you bind data to grid, make sure, data is again fetched from the DB – Muhammad Akhtar

Yes - This worked! Thank you Muhd. Akthar!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your gridview in the updatepanel, No need to add trigger for paging

--In PageIndexchanging event, where you bind data to grid, make sure, data is again fetched from the DB

--Make sure gridview paging is enable...

```
AllowPaging="True"
```